# How to load L.geoJson from url with input of zoom,x and y in javascript?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I used below code to fetch geojson data from backend API but input data not passing

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:3000/api/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {

                geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(response, {
                    style: yourLeafletStyle
                }).addTo(map);
            }
        });
```

below issue raised `http://localhost:3000/api/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.geojson`

How to use the L.geojson with backend call with input values?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use this library

https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson

but it's only compatible with Leaflet <= 0.7.x

Comment: still I'm getting issue `/$%7Bz%7D/$%7Bx%7D/$%7By%7D.geojson`

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. I've added code snippet to my answer.

Comment: I'm using this in leaflet geojson format. I need to pass this values dynamically

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question initially.